# Непонятность с установкой lamp-server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Поставил lamp - server на убунту 11,04. При установке 3 раза просил указать пароль к мускулу. Я оставил поля пустыми. Вопрос - будет ли теперь имя пользователя - root пароль - "" ?

Answer (score 1):

sudo `apt-get purge apache2 mysql-server php5 php5-mysql phpmyadmin` - удали, сделай autoclean и update, установи апач, мускул, пхп, и пхпмайадмин если надо и нигде не оставляй пустые пароли и будет счастье)

Answer (score 0):

Молодец. Вот теперь будут проблемы при создании и работе с mysql, пока пользователю пароль не поставите.

Comment: Так. Тогда как его удалить lamp - server? И я что то не пойму - пароль запрашивался 3 раза - какой из них пользовательский? И как допустим теперь можно поставить пользователю пароль?(чтоб не переустанавливать)

Answer (score 0):

может первый раз спрашивал пароль пользователя, затем пароль su, затем пароль на mysql.
Если ты имел ввиду не подрят запрашивал. 
Попробуй попасть в mysql так ~sudo mysql -u root спросит пароль от su вводишь возможно не спросит пароль от mysql а там уже добавишь пользователя с root правами